# gzip compressed file streams in C++

Tags: c++, iostream

My loader looks like that:

```
void LispAna::loadF() {
    formatives.rehash(2991);
    std::ifstream fin("data.txt");
    formCondition st;

    std::string key;
    std::string tmp;
    int itmp;

    for (std::string row; getline(fin, row, '\n');) {
        //"a\t0\txx\tA\n"
        std::istringstream ss(row);

        getline(ss, key, '\t');

        //pos
        getline(ss, tmp, '\t');
        st.pos = *(tmp.c_str());

        //types
        getline(ss, tmp, '\t');
        st.types = tmp;

        //condition
        getline(ss, tmp, '\t');
        st.condition = tmp;

        //if(ok)?
        formatives.insert(std::pair<std::string, formCondition>(key, st));
    }
}
```

Id like to replace `std::ifstream` witch own made `zifstream`.
That can easily used for reading `zlib` compressed text files.

```
zifstream fin("data.txt.gz");
//..
for (std::string row; getline(fin, row, '\n');) {
//..
}
```

I have `tinfl.c` v1.11. 
And I dont have a clue witch class to extend and what functions to implement to achieve that.
I dont need seek. Just simple linear reading and some basic error checking.
Don't even need full header support, data files are own made.

Comment: Closely related: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html

Comment: The class to extend is std::streambuf, which handles the lower level reading and writing for stream calsses, I'm sure you can find examples with google.

Comment: @john It's not unusual to extend `std::istream` as well, for user convenience.  (But you're right that it's in the class derived from `std::streambuf` where all of the action takes place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think Boost already has what you are looking for.  If
you can use it, it would certainly be simpler than rewriting the
code yourself.

Otherwise: you'll need to define a filtering streambuf which
does the compression, and forwards the compressed data on to
another streambuf (almost certainly a `filebuf` opened in binary
mode).  Just derive from `std::streambuf`, with a pointer to the
final target `streambuf` in your class.  At the least, you'll
have to overwrite the function `overflow`; you might want to
override `xsputn` as well.

The actual `zifstream` is then very simple: something like:

```
class zifstream : private std::filebuf, private zistreambuf, public std::istream
{
public:
    zifstream( std::string const& filename )
        : std::filebuf( filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary )
        , zistreambuf( static_cast<std::filebuf>( this ) )
        , std::istream( static_cast<zistreambuf>( this ) )
    {
    }
};
```

is likely sufficient.  (The standard classes which derive from
`std::istream` also provide a `rdbuf` function which hides the
one in the base class, and returns the derived type.  This is
more a "nice to have", in a few particular cases, and not really
necessary.)

Note that if you're reading using locales other than `"C"`,
you'll have to do the code translation in the filtering buffer;
doing it in the filebuf will *not* work.  (Again, Boost has the
necessary support.)

Comment: I cant use boost. That example seems what i need. But im bit lost. How can i read filebuf from inside zistreambuf.

Comment: @Paxmees The same way you'd read it anywhere else.  Your
`zistreambuf` class will have a `std::streambuf* source;`, and
to get characters, it would use `source->sgetn` or
`source->sgetc`.  Apparently Boost has archived the reference
article:
http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/att-49459/fltrsbf1.htm,
which explains how to do this in detail (from _C++ Reports_,
Sept., 1998, so it's not exactly a new idea).